# Is it possible to use selenium on an arm64 device which has a linux server?

Tags: linux, selenium, kotlin, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to run selenium on an arm64 device with linux server, since I cannot install chrome on this device, I want to use chromium or firefox browser in headless mode. But I'm getting different errors every time I run my selenium program. here is the error log while using chromium:

```
/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux-arm64/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at dev.emad.selenium.book.Main$Companion.main(Main.kt:43)
    at dev.emad.selenium.book.Main.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
System info: host: 'FriendlyELEC', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '5.10.60', java.version: '11.0.14.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:226)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    ... 8 more
```

I have tried xvfb but it didn't help, And here is he code that I'm using:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()
            val chromeOptions = ChromeOptions().apply {
                setHeadless(true)
                addArguments(
                    "--disable-infobars",
                    "--disable-extensions",
                    "--disable-application-cache",
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                    "--dns-prefetch-disable",
                    "--ignore-ssl-errors",
                    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--window-size=1920,1080",
                    "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
                )
            }
            chromeOptions.setBinary("/usr/bin/chromium-browser")


            driver = ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
            driver.get("https://bing.com")
```